# Forge ControlGroup.addControl(Button) -> Slide-In Transition

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is there a possibility to have a transition when adding dynamically a new button to the control group?
For example, in this code, it would be nice to show the new button with a slide-In.

```
valuesOfParameter.forEach(valueOfParameter => {
          // iterative Button
          var buttonIterativ = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button(valueOfParameter);
          // Click Event
          buttonIterativ.onClick = (event) => {
            console.log(valueOfParameter);
          };
          buttonIterativ.addClass(valueOfParameter);
          controlGroup.addControl(buttonIterativ);
          // controlGroup.addControl(buttonIterativ);
          $('#' + valueOfParameter).append('<style>.' + valueOfParameter + ':before{content: attr(data-before); font-size: 20px; color: white;}</style>');
          $('#' + valueOfParameter.toString()).attr('data-before', valueOfParameter);
        });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to go with CSS3 animation - you can pull it off with no code level changes required, e.g.:

```
.buttonSlide_in{
 animation: slideMe .7s ease-in;
}

@keyframes slideMe{
    0%{
        transform: skewX(53deg) translateX(-500px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    60%{
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
    62%{
        transform: skewX(0deg) translateX(30px);
    }
    70%{
        transform: skew(-20deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    80%{
        transform: skew(0deg) translate(0);
    }
    90%{
        transform: skew(-5deg);
    }
    100%{
        transform: skew(0deg);
    }
}
```

See [here](https://css3-tutorial.net/) to get started and you'd get the attention from the right community if you add more relevant tags such as `HTML/CSS animation` to your question